# Is there any benefit to removing the X-Mas tree from my land?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I noticed with the holiday patch that there are new trees and shrubs that spawn on my land.  One popped up today, being specifically an X-Mas tree - which costs 25,000 gold to remove.   Is there any benefit to removing this X-Mas tree?  Is there any benefit to leaving it there?

**It is noticeably the most expensive obstacle to remove yet.**

[image]

Comment: If they're the same as last year, [EBongo's observations on the subject](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/in-clash-of-clans-what-do-i-get-for-christmas-tree-removal/) might be useful.

Comment: seems to be slightly different - reward & cosmetically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up removing it as I am almost certain it provides no defensive traits to my base. Opposing troops just walked right past it.

**It took 30 seconds to remove and I was rewarded with 75,000 Gold.** A 50k profit in 30 seconds makes it well worth it to remove it from the land.

Comment: This answer is out of date since trees are now spawning presents.

Answer (score 4):

X-Mas trees are back again this year, and once again you can cut them down for a small resource profit.  (It appears to be 75k payout for 25k invested = 50k profit, just like last year)

**However** - now X-Mas trees [also spawn presents!](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/in-clash-of-clans-what-do-i-get-for-christmas-tree-removal/)  If you remove the tree, you lose the chance to get presents from it.  The presents I've seen so far only give 5k elixir a pop.

Thus it may be more profitable in the short-term to leave these trees alone, at least until they stop dropping presents!

Comment: I was just coming over here to ask about presents, as I noticed that earlier today. Farm presents now, cut it down for gold later.  :)

Comment: Just curious, but would you happen to know how often presents may spawn and include that in your answer? I've only seen the one that was initially spawned when the Christmas tree appeared.

Comment: @Ellesedil, I've seen screenshots of people's bases with 5 presents under the tree, but like you my tree has only spawned one in the couple of days I've had it.  So I don't know at this point.

Comment: The maximum of 5 presents is refuted by the comment by Bluntacide at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196833/what-are-the-statistics-and-mechanics-behind-the-spawning-of-presents-from-the-2. He or she claims to have 11 presents with at 2 trees.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich, I'll monitor my trees and update my answer if I see presents spawning past what I've stated is the limit.

Comment: @agent86 I just raided a base with a total of 20 presents around three trees.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich, I've seen those too and I wasn't sure if they'd removed trees and left presents or not.  Mine finally spawned a 6th present, so I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit to leaving it other than it makes you look cool; but if you remove it (which costs 25K gold) it rewards you with 75k gold. So it's either a 50
K profit or looking cool. I would choose looking cool over a small profit.

Answer (score -4):

Chopping it down gives you 300 gems and the gold