# If you remove a Christmas tree, do you get another one?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If you remove a Christmas tree do you get another one? I want it to be more to the side so it doesn't stay close to the center. Any help?

Comment: anybody knows what they give if they get renoved?

Comment: @codermaster, there's a question for this already, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145585/is-there-any-benefit-to-removing-the-x-mas-tree-from-my-land/196404#196404

Answer (score 0):

Christmas tree decorations spawn at random. It doesn't matter how many you already have, so you don't have to remove your current one to get another one. I currently have 2 christmas trees (both on the side) and the only restriction on spawning seems to be if they have space, so they spawn like a normal obstacle, except with a less chance of spawning (only about a 1/50 chance).

Answer (score 0):

I have not removed any Christmas trees yet.
I received a second tree today.
Both of my Christmas trees have so far spawned 1 present each good for 5000 elixir each.