# What are the statistics and mechanics behind the Spawning of Presents from the 2014 X-Mas Trees?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Apparently the 2014 X-mas trees in Clash of Clans spawn presents. The trees give you 50k  gold surplus when removed and are able to spawn presents which in turn are worth 5k Elixir. Also, a friend of mine just told me that he got 25 Gems from the tree.

What I did not find when searching for it is how the spawning of presents works in detail. The only data I found was that a tree can only have 5 presents around it at a given time. This is mentioned in an answer to the question "[Is there any benefit to removing the X-Mas tree from my land?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145585/is-there-any-benefit-to-removing-the-x-mas-tree-from-my-land)" but wrong. I raided a base which had three trees with two times seven and once six present around them.

Does each tree have its own spawn chance?

Is there a total limit of how many presents any given tree can spawn in total?

Comment: I'll keep it for as long as I can. I don't really need the gold -I already get largely enough through raiding as it is for the elixir- so... definitely keeping it here :) As for the gifts, I have 2 right now. That's like, 1 every 2 days or something?

Comment: @Jerry: I got a tree almost a week ago and I've only had one present, which seems to have initially come with the tree. I quickly consumed the present when I noticed it, but haven't gotten another one since despite keeping the tree around.

Comment: @Ellesedil Hm, it might be random after all.

Comment: I'm wondering if more presents only appear if you leave the first one.

Comment: I'm on my second tree now, and my first one had just one present and hasn't spawned any others.  The second one I've left the present alone, haven't seen any new ones.

Comment: @agent86: I'm doing the very same thing. Second tree still has it's originial gift, but I haven't seen any additional presents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add my own "statistics" for sake of completeness.

Since the patch I got three trees. The first two spawned within the first few days and had one present each. I cut those down because - obviously - I could not find satisfying information about how presents were spawned and such and I wanted the gold for an update. Also I was hoping for this ominous gem heap ;-)

I currently have a third tree. After it spawned 4 presents I cleared it and it spawned 2 more so far. This means that a single tree can spawn more then 5 presents in total. It also means that I should have kept the other two trees...

Summing all answers and comments up I would say that the spawning of trees and presents is totally random. According to http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Obstacles 2% of spawned obstacles are trees. Whether the spawning of presents is in any way influenced by other obstacles stays a mystery for now but I'd dare say: no.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a tree for about a week and a second for about 4 days and never have I gotten a present after the first spawned one

Answer (score 1):

The first tree I got spawned about a week ago I tapped the present unknowingly taking the 5k elixir, no other presents have spawned on that tree since but I got another tree with yet another present, I will be patient with this one and see what happens once the Xmas update is over.

Comment: Three days later and both trees have a total of 7 between them the first tree spawned two more yesterday as well as the second which made it five now today I woke up to two extra presents and I'm totally waiting till Christmas to open them haha

Comment: Do not claim your gifts!!!! Even more of them spawned and I don't believe there is a limit to how many there are per tree because my second tree has six of them now and my first tree has five now. 11 presents!!! I'm stoked!

Answer (score 1):

I have only had one tree, and only one present,  which I claimed immediately.  I have people in my clan with two trees, one of which has two presents. Must be totally random, but kinda annoying many of us have only had one tree when others are getting multiple of both...

Answer (score 1):

Having a XMas Tree that only spawns a single present seems to be a [common](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/in-clash-of-clans-what-do-i-get-for-christmas-tree-removal/#comment-1751078781) [problem.](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans/comments/2pff1g/misc_what_is_wrong_with_xmas_trees/)

My clan mates have also mentioned that they've only gotten one present from each tree as of last week.  I've tested various theories, but as far as I can tell there's no rhyme or reason to it.

Both of my trees spawned 2 extra presents this morning (12/22), and they'd both previously had just the first one and no others.  I'm wondering if there was perhaps a glitch preventing more presents from spawning, and they fixed it over the weekend.

One tree still had its original present, the other did not.

I came back after another day (12/23) and both of my trees had *four* additional presents.  In the meantime, I've not done anything in particular that could be considered different or novel about my base - I mostly left it alone for about 16 hours.

For the record, I keep my obstacles to a minimum.